# The form data going to another page while action set to another page

Tags: html, forms, navigation

I have a form in which the attribute action is set to go to a page but whenever i press the submit button its taking the data to another page.

Comment: There is no [mcve] here, so this needs to be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

while writing your form use post method if you are using get method or use get if using post. one of them uses to carry data while navigating to target.. so just change your form method..